# Facebook Redirect loop when accessing developers.facebook.com/apps

Tags: facebook, redirect

I am unable to access [developers.facebook.com/apps](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) due to an infinite redirect loop. I have cleared my cache and cookies but to no avail. Occasionally it lets me access a few pages, but I am unable to test development for my my Facebook app.

Comment: did someone add you as a test user to an app?

Comment: No, I am just trying to create an app but I can't visit developers.facebook.com/apps !! as Facebook enters an endless loop

Comment: well, today I also added a user as tester of my app and the same thing happened to him. when i removed him from testers, it became normal again. if that's the case with you too, someone may have added you before as a tester maybe, if not, i don't know.